# azure_rm_dnszones cannot find resourcegroup

Tags: ansible

Im trying to create a public DNS zones in Azure, using the ansible_rm_dnszones module, and it just doesn't work. Im running **ansible-playbook 2.9.3** on **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**. After doing AZ LOGIN successfully and running this playbook. The RG poc-rg_publicdns i created manually.

This playbook needs to use proxy-servers. i've setup proxies as environment variables using **export**

```
export http_proxy=http://<ip>:3128  
export https_proxy=http://<ip>:3128
```

Playbook code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Creating zone kasperstesting123.dk
    azure_rm_dnszone:
      resource_group: poc-rg_publicdns
      name: kasperstesting123.dk
      type: public
```

im getting

```
TASK [Creating zone kasperstesting123.dk] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error retrieving resource group poc-rg_publicdns - Resource group 'poc-rg_publicdns' could not be found."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. it turns out having multiple subscription, my default active subscription was not the one i tried to create the objects on. To switch subscriptions, use the az account set tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-set

```
az account set -s <subid>
```